# Bash: Extract Range with Regular Expressioin (maybe sed?)

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file that is *similar* to this:

```
<many lines of stuff>
SUMMARY:
<some lines of stuff>
END OF SUMMARY
```

I want to extract just the stuff between `SUMMARY` and `END OF SUMMARY`.  I suspect I can do this with sed but I am not sure how.  I know I can modify the stuff in between with this:

```
sed "/SUMMARY/,/END OF SUMMARY/ s/replace/with/" fileName
```

(But not sure how to just extract that stuff).

I am Bash on Solaris.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed -n "/SUMMARY/,/END OF SUMMARY/p" fileName
```

Comment: This also matches: 

....SUMMARY
....END OF SUMMARY

Adding '^' to require matching the NULL string at the beginning of pattern space:

sed -n "/^SUMMARY/,/^END OF SUMMARY/p"

Comment: If you do that it is probably a good Idea to add an end an end of line marker as well.  Ie: `sed -n "/^SUMMARY$/,/^END OF SUMMARY$/p"`

Answer (score 1):

If `Perl` is fine you can use:

```
perl -e 'print $1 if(`cat FILE_NAME`=~/SUMMARY:\n(.*?)END OF SUMMARY/s);'
```

Comment: Yeah, I like perl too but my team are more seddy people.

Comment: I like Perl too, but this one really sounds more like a job for sed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to print the marker lines:

```
sed '1,/SUMMARY/d;/END OF SUMMARY/,$d' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work using (FreeBSD) sed as well:

```
sed -E -n -e '/^SUMMARY:/,/^END OF SUMMARY/{ /^SUMMARY:/d; /^END OF SUMMARY/d; p;}' file.txt
```

Comment: What is the advantage of that over `sed -n "/^SUMMARY$/,/^END OF SUMMARY$/p" fileName` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
$ echo 'many
lines
of
stuff
SUMMARY:
this is the summary
over two lines
END OF SUMMARY' | awk '
    BEGIN              {e=0}
    /^END OF SUMMARY$/ {e=0}
                       {if (e==1) {print}}
    /^SUMMARY:$/       {e=1}'
```

which outputs:

```
this is the summary
over two lines
```

Not all implementations of `awk` will require the `BEGIN` clause but I always like to include explicit initialisation.

It works by using an echo flag (`e`) to decide whether you're in the summary section or not.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris , use nawk

```
#!/bin/bash
nawk '
/SUMMARY/{
 gsub(".*SUMMARY:","");
 f=1
}
/END OF SUMMARY/{f=0;
 gsub("END OF SUMMARY.*","")
}f' file
```

output

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 <many lines of stuff>
4 5 6 SUMMARY: 7 8 9
<some lines of stuff>
END OF SUMMARY blah
blah

$ ./shell.sh
 7 8 9
<some lines of stuff>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another sed version just doing a multi-line print & quit (which may be suitable for extracting a range of lines from a large file):

```
sed -E -n -e '/^SUMMARY:$/{n;h;};/^END OF SUMMARY$/!H;/^END OF SUMMARY$/{g;p;q;}' fileName | sed 1d
```

For a multi-line sed script pretty well explained see:

http://ilfilosofo.com/blog/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/

Comment: Hum.  Had a look at that reference but I still think it that is better to do replaces using a range rather than buffers.  Interested to hear if/why you think buffers are better.